# LDA - plot boundaries

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am using the Iris - file and would like to plot the separation boundary / area of the three classes:

I have first reduced all features up to two LDA - Coponents with the following code:

```
# Load the Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target


# Perform LDA
lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
X_lda = lda.fit_transform(X, y)


# Plot the data points
cmap = ListedColormap(['red', 'green', 'blue'])
for target, color, marker in zip(np.unique(y), ['r', 'g', 'b'], ['s', 'x', 'o']):
    plt.scatter(X_lda[y == target, 0], X_lda[y == target, 1], c=color, cmap=cmap, marker=marker, label=target, edgecolors='black')

# Set plot labels and limits
plt.title('Linear Discriminant Analysis (Iris Dataset)')
plt.xlabel('LDA Component 1')
plt.ylabel('LDA Component 2')
plt.legend()
```

**Result:**

[image: iris dataset]

Now i want to plot the decision boundaries of these three classes.
Ive tried by using:

```
# Define the decision boundary
x1_min, x1_max = X_lda[:, 0].min() - 1, X_lda[:, 0].max() + 1
x2_min, x2_max = X_lda[:, 1].min() - 1, X_lda[:, 1].max() + 1
xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, 0.02),
                      np.arange(x2_min, x2_max, 0.02))

Z = lda.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)

Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
```

But i get the error:
ValueError: X has 2 features, but LinearDiscriminantAnalysis is expecting 4 features as input.

How can i plot the boundaries between these three classes?

Answer (score 0):

The error says you have trained the data with `X`, which is an array of `N*4`, four features, then you used the same model `lda` for predicting an array of `N*2`, so the dimension is miss matched.

If you want to predict the data with `np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T`, you need to initialize another model then train the model with two features.

Then you can plot the boundary with [DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.html#sklearn.inspection.DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator)

The full codes :

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from sklearn.inspection import DecisionBoundaryDisplay



iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

lda = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()
X_lda = lda.fit_transform(X, y)

# Create another model for two features
lda_2 = LinearDiscriminantAnalysis().fit(X_lda, y)

_, ax = plt.subplots()
DecisionBoundaryDisplay.from_estimator(
    lda_2,
    X_lda,
    cmap=plt.cm.Paired,
    ax=ax,
    response_method="predict",
    plot_method="pcolormesh",
    shading="auto",
    eps=0.2,
)


# Plot the data points
cmap = ListedColormap(['red', 'green', 'blue'])
for target, color, marker in zip(np.unique(y), ['r', 'g', 'b'], ['s', 'x', 'o']):
    ax.scatter(X_lda[y == target, 0], X_lda[y == target, 1], c=color, cmap=cmap, marker=marker, label=target, edgecolors='black')

# Set plot labels and limits
plt.title('Linear Discriminant Analysis (Iris Dataset)')
plt.xlabel('LDA Component 1')
plt.ylabel('LDA Component 2')
plt.legend()
```

The output :
[image]